# Memory upgrade Swap question

Tags: ram, swap

I just doubled my physical memory to 8 gig. Do I need to change swap size?

Comment: Unless you were swapping regularly, you can probably reduce your swap size, Of course, we don't know what you are running.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`.